# Using multiple tables inner join on one key item. Can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

For the life of me I can not figure out where I have went wrong
I am pulling the data from these multiple tables but no data appearing

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chars uc
INNER JOIN zone_settings t ON uc.pos_zone = t.zoneid    
INNER JOIN char_look v ON uc.charid = v.charid  
INNER JOIN char_jobs y ON uc.charid = y.charid  
INNER JOIN char_stats n ON uc.charid = n.charid     
INNER JOIN char_profile p ON uc.charid = p.charid 
WHERE `accid`='".$user["id"]."' ORDER BY `charid`");
```

Thanks kwolfe using LEFT JOIN and Removing the ORDER BY it works now. Here is the code.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chars uc
LEFT JOIN zone_settings t ON uc.pos_zone = t.zoneid     
LEFT JOIN char_look v ON uc.charid = v.charid   
LEFT JOIN char_jobs y ON uc.charid = y.charid   
LEFT JOIN char_stats n ON uc.charid = n.charid  
LEFT JOIN char_profile p ON uc.charid = p.charid 
WHERE `accid`='".$user["id"]."'");
```

Comment: What is wrong ?   Error message?   No data?   Not sure what your question is?

Comment: Coming up blank screen

Comment: Post the query directly into the db using whatever tool you use (and a hard coded value for id of course), establish whether you have an invalid query or have something wrong with your PHP logic.

Comment: @Cups Here is what it output    [SQL] SELECT * FROM chars uc
LEFT JOIN zone_settings t ON uc.pos_zone = t.zoneid    
LEFT JOIN char_look v ON uc.charid = v.charid  
LEFT JOIN char_jobs y ON uc.charid = y.charid  
LEFT JOIN char_stats n ON uc.charid = n.charid     
LEFT JOIN char_profile p ON uc.charid = p.charid 
WHERE `accid`='1000' ORDER BY `charid`

[Err] 1052 - Column 'charid' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: probably need to tell it which table you are getting charid from: eg. ORDER BY uc.charid - or - ORDER BY p.charid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to LEFT JOINS to see if your missing a relationship along the way (INNER JOIN will only show data where a relationship is made for each table, in this case ALL tables.)

Comment: still nothing on screen

Comment: In that case, nothing is matching your WHERE criteria, or you do not have any data at all in your first table (chars)

Comment: Or... I'm wrong in assuming you know that you have to actually retrieve the results from $result, and echo it.

Comment: I got working with LEFT JOIN need to edit two of the table names. Thank you so much!